# Where to save a credit card number?

Tags: database, cookies, credit-card

If you are making a webapp with online purchases and you want to be able to save a user's credit card info so they don't have to type it in again, where is it stored? Do you generally store that encrypted on the database? Or is it best to save it in an encrypted browser cookie? Just curious.

Comment: Well yes, using encryption and databases. However, if you are planning on storing credit card details for a future project I hope you are PCI compliant and have liability insurance.

Comment: Thanks @Mark! I am not currently setting up anything with credit cards, but that is good to know for the future.